# ALERT: [pool www] user has not been defined when using thecodingmachine/php:7.1-v3-fpm-node10

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

i was trying lately to use thecodingmachine/php:7.1-v3-fpm-node10 image as my fpm container for local development and was surprised by this error message:

```
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ALERT: [pool www] user has not been defined
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ALERT: [pool www] user has not been defined
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
php-fpm_1   | [24-Sep-2020 20:05:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

When i looked into `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` i have discovered that the line with `user = www-data` is still commented, although i have absolutely no idea why. The same image worked ok a week ago.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i have figured out what the error was. I had containers built without enabled WSL 2 within my Docker for Windows so when I have switched to WSL2 the containers weren't rebuilt. After pruning containers and rebuilding them it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

The errors in the Question are exactly the errors which I get if I completely remove the the `www.conf` file, for example:

`mv /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf_bak`.

What is strange is that it seems like it's not possible to remove the default pool, and that's the case even if another named pool exists.

Anyway, to your problem, it could be that something with the paths and the include statement at the bottom of `php-fpm.conf` has changed and the www.conf pool configuration is not found.